# CMake: undefined reference in function main

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to compile a simple C++ app with CMake but I got

```
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target mylib
[ 25%] Linking CXX shared library libmylib.so
[ 50%] Built target mylib
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target app
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable app
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/app.dir/app.cc.o: in function `main':
app.cc:(.text.startup+0x38): undefined reference to `MyTest::MyTest()'
/usr/bin/ld: app.cc:(.text.startup+0x40): undefined reference to `MyTest::add()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/app.dir/build.make:98: app] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:111: CMakeFiles/app.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Source code below

lib.h

```
class MyTest {
public:
    MyTest();
    void add();
};
```

lib.cc

```
#include "lib.h"
MyTest::MyTest() {
}
void MyTest::add() {
}
```

app.cc

```
#include "lib.h"

int main() {
    MyTest test;
    test.add();
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17 FATAL_ERROR)
message("CMAKE_VERSION: ${CMAKE_VERSION}")
project(debug C CXX)

set(RELEASE_FLAGS "-O3 -fvisibility=hidden -fPIC")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${RELEASE_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${RELEASE_FLAGS} -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer")

include_directories(.)
add_library(mylib SHARED "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib.cc")
target_link_libraries(mylib PRIVATE protobuf::libprotobuf)

add_executable(app "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/app.cc")
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE mylib)
```

I have linked `mylib` target to `app` target already but for some reason, I still got `undefined reference` error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is that you're not exporting your `MyTest` class / its interface functions. See also https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html. Good job with posting an [mre] though.

Comment: Since you use `-fvisibility=hidden`, then you should now that it prevents exporting symbols by default. CMake has platform-independent representation of this flag: [<LANG>_VISIBILITY_PRESET](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LANG_VISIBILITY_PRESET.html), so it is better to use that property.